# Not able to see data i've passed through an array. No error when checked in console too,it shows an empty array in console. (Im not using API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, jsx, react-props

[ProductDetails.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHYF9.png)
[ProductDetailList.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DuKs.png)

I'm currently working on a React project where I'm rendering product and delivery details using components. I have two components: `ProductDetailsList.jsx` and `ProductDetails.jsx`.

`ProductDetailsList.jsx` contains an array of product details and an array of delivery details, which are passed as props to the `ProductDetails` component. In `ProductDetails.jsx`, I map through these arrays to render the details in separate sections.

However, I'm facing an issue with rendering these details properly. Despite passing the props correctly, the details don't seem to render as expected. I've checked the console logs within `ProductDetails.jsx` and confirmed that the props are being received correctly.

I'm not sure where the issue lies – whether it's with the way I'm passing the props or with how I'm rendering them in the `ProductDetails` component.

Comment: Please do not post code in images, edit your question to remove the images, and post the text itself.

Comment: The title of your question says "empty array" but the body of your question says "confirmed props are being received correctly." Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make your question clear and appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it may be closed.

Comment: `don't seem to render as expected` - what do you expect? what do you observe instead?